# Trying to settimeout for a function and passvariable - doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I have a function that passes this... I need this function to be executed 1/3 seconds after a button got clicked so what I thought of doing is:

```
setTimeout("somefunction(this)", 3000);
```

As I know that setTimeout("", x); works with ""
but it doesn't work.

I've tried without the "" and it wont work either I tried to:

```
  setTimeout("somefunction("+this+")", 3000);
```

and still won't work. Did like an hour of attempts at this.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a closure

```
var that = this;
setTimeout( function(){ somefunction(that); }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

timeouts are asynchronous events and so the context is lost. One way to preserve it is to bind it via an immediately-executed function.

```
setTimeout((function(that) {
    return function() { somefunction(that); };
})(this), 3000);
```

Another way would be to make a reference to the outer scope in a variable, as @epascarello's answer shows.

It is always better to pass function references to `setTimeout` and `setInterval` than strings, because the latter are evaluated, and eval'ing is evil.

Comment: Thanks utkanos you guys both have about the same answer